# Values from Array to hashMap

Tags: java, jdbc

I have values retrieved from a pl/sql function and it is stored in as

```
Array arr = callablestatement.getArray(1);
```

I would like to store the values in a HashMap, something like

```
 hashMap.put("Dt", arr.get(0));
```

How can I do this? Or are there any other efficient ways to do this?

Comment: There is no method called `arr.get(0));` to put the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here **arr** is of type **java.sql.Array**. So you have to change it to java array type.

```
String[] array = (String[]) arr.getArray(); //as getArray() returns an java.lang.Object
```

Now you can add it to hashmap using

```
hashMap.put("key1", array[0]);
hashMap.put("key2", array[1]);
.......
```